# Rails 4 query nested resources based on a subset of parent resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, activerecord, geocoding

I am running a basic rails 4 app that uses Google maps to locate users on a map.

I am trying to write a query that finds a set of users by multiple attributes.  Relationships are:

```
User has_one :location
User has_many :children

Location belongs_to :user
Children belongs_to :user

@close = Location.near([current_user.location.latitude, current_user.location.longitude], params[:distance])
@close = @close.joins(user: :children).where('locations.users.children.count <= ?', params[:number_of_children]) if params[:number_of_children].present?
```

I am using the Geocoded gem, which provides the `.near` method.  I query a set of locations by `params[:distance]`, and I need to query the number of `children.count <= params[:number_of_children]` based on that set of objects.

```
PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: locations.users.children.count
```

**Edit**

The initialization of the `@close` instance var, gets a list of locations near a given location.  I am then trying to filter those objects by a given associated `locations.users.children.count`.

Comment: it should be :users in @close.joins

Comment: I modified to what you noted, I wonder if I need to modify it to be joins.(users: :children)?  I tried and it doesn't work but...

Comment: You have a "typo". What you want to get is `users.children_count`, given you implement a counter cache on your `User has_many :children` association.

Comment: I don't have a counter method on the association but I think I can write one, I'll give it a shot

Comment: The counter_cache worked great.  If you (Michael Szyndel) want to create an answer I can  mark it solved.